# Want to add some content to the tab in magento 2 admin view product page

Tags: magento2, product

[image]

I want to add some text to the admin product view in Magento 2 please help me, someone.check the screeshot where i want to show some info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of **After** plugin to achieve your goal. Below are the general steps to follow (I assume that you know how to create a custom module from scratch):

**Step 1.** Create a custom module (Say: **Stack_ProductPlugin**) and define a plugin in **app/code/Stack/ProductPlugin/etc/di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery">
        <plugin name="add_gallery_text" type="Stack\ProductPlugin\Plugin\Gallery" sortOrder="-1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create the plugin file **Gallery.php** at **app/code/Stack/ProductPlugin/Plugin** path and add the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\ProductPlugin\Plugin;
class Gallery
{
    public function afterGetElementHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery $subject, $result) {
        return "my custom text".$result;
    }
}
```

After refreshing the cache, you should be able to see the text **my custom text** above gallery.